# Graph styling using `HighlightGraph`, `GraphHighlightStyle` and `VertexStyle`at the same time

Tags: graphs-and-networks, style

I like the style when a graph is highlighted by `HighlightGraph` with parameter `GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"`.

But I want to override the style of some vertices with different style.

I did this with the following code, but the style of vertices `13` and `17` does not mach the style of other vertices.

I want to change just the tint of the reddish color to something like greenish, but so that other properties of the vertices stay the same.

How to achieve this?

```
g = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Skeleton"];
HighlightGraph[g, {PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g]]}, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Thick", 
   13 | 17 -> {VertexStyle -> {Green}}}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I had to do it manually - manually matching the tint of colors:

```
g = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Skeleton"];
HighlightGraph[g, {PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g]]}, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Thick", 
   13 | 17 -> {VertexStyle -> {RGBColor[{128, 217, 128}/255], 
       EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, RGBColor[{0, 179, 0}/255]]]}}}]
```

[image]